# how/when deadlock can happen in my code

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, prepared-statement

I am using mysql database
I tried to find the reason for deadlock but I am unable to find it so pasting my code here.

Can anyone please tell me `how/when this deadlock is coming`.

Below code is executed by `5 threads simultaneously` but totally on different records (first thread is executing for first 100 of `F_Table` then another thread will execute for 101 to 200 records of F_Table and so on).

```
String deleteFQuery = "DELETE FROM F_Table WHERE ID IN (?,?,? ...25 times )"; // Deleting old record for given id
String insertFQuery = "INSERT INTO F_Table (columns..) values (?,?..)"; // Reinserting for same id same with updated values
String deleteMpQuery = "DELETE FROM MP_Table WHERE ID IN (?,?,? ...25 times)";
String updateMQuery = "UPDATE M_Table  SET COLUMN1=? WHERE ID IN (?,?,? ...25 times)";

pstmt1 = con.prepareStatement(insertFQuery);
for (i -> 100 times) {
    pstmt1.setString(1, value1); //Values will be set from a list which is getting iterated in this for loop.
    pstmt1.setString(2, value2);
    pstmt1.setString(3, value3);
    pstmt1.setString(4, value4);

    pstmt1.addBatch();

    if ((i1) % 25 == 0) {
        pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement(deleteFuzzyQuery);
        pstmt2.setInt() //this will set 25 values in for loop
        pstmt2.executeUpdate();
        pstmt2.close();

        synchronized (this) {
            pstmt1.executeBatch(); // Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
                               // Exception : class java.sql.BatchUpdateException
            pstmt1.close();
        }

        pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement(deleteMpQuery);
        pstmt2.setInt() //this will set 25 values in for loop
        pstmt2.executeUpdate();
        pstmt2.close();

        pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement(updateMQuery);
        pstmt2.setInt() //this will set 25 values in for loop
        pstmt2.executeUpdate();
        pstmt2.close();

        con.commit();

        pstmt1 = con.prepareStatement(insertFQuery);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Deadlock is coming once in 10 time or so.

Thanks.

**Update:**

After executing `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` I found below log content. I am really new to read this. Can anyone please help me to find what kind of lock it is having.

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2014-11-13 13:13:42 1070
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 8871318, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 312, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 7761, OS thread handle 0x1360, query id 145308 dbuser update
INSERT INTO F_TABLE(ID, ...) VALUES ('1',...)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 28831 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `dbname`
.`f_table` trx id 8871318 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 8871319, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 312, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 7763, OS thread handle 0x1070, query id 145309 dbuser update
INSERT INTO F_TABLE(ID, ...) VALUES ('101',...)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 28831 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `dbname`
.`f_table` trx id 8871319 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 28831 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `dbname`
.`f_table` trx id 8871319 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

**Update 2:**

`Added synchronized block`. Will that help to avoid deadlock while executing `pstmt1.executeBatch();`?

Comment: Is that the actual code? You never execute `pstmt2`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing out. Updated the question

Comment: Where are try and catch, and what kind of For you are using?.

Comment: I tried to reduce code to paste it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` (if your db engine is innodb) in mysql.You will get detailed 
engine status with last detected deadlock details.There you will see which query goes in deadlock.Now to able to answer your question result from show engine query will be helpful.

Comment: I am getting single row table having header as `Type, Name, Status` and row values as `InnoDB, [Blank], 2014-11-13 ...`.

Comment: I got logs from cmd. Was executing in phpmyadmin webapp.

Comment: will you able to find "LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK" Entry ??

Comment: yes, I found that but am new to read it. I am pasting it in my question. Can you please have look at it.

Comment: Your inserts query are clashing.Main issue with your code is synchronization. At some point one of your query lock some row and at that same time some other query waiting for lock to be released so if you synchronize your threads properly then you might avoid deadlock occurrence in your applications.

Comment: I am inserting new row in `f_table`, at that time what type of lock it will acquire? (Means I guess at same time both the Transactions are trying to insert in f_table)

Comment: As you suggested about synchronization, I have added `synchronized` block in my code (updated my question), will it help to avoid deadlock?

Comment: yes it will surely help to avoid deadlock.what else you can do is verifying innodb engine status to check whether deadlock occurs or not.Also have a look on setAutocommit off and commiting transaction so if deadlock occurs you can catch the exception in try catch block and restarting that failed transaction once again.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have done as you have mentioned. Just one thing was pending i.e. restarting the transaction after deadlock. I have 2 queries. 1. Is it the accepted way of handling deadlock by restarting the transaction. 2. Can you tell me if I change database from mysql to oracle the same implementation of restarting transaction is recommended.

Comment: Answer to your first is question is Yes.No matter whether you have good system with better hardware or how neatly you optimize and synchronized your code; deadlocks can occur.So it is better to have fail-safe strategy by restarting your failed transactions.And yes it also applies to all databases.